# Why i am getting else syntax error in else condition?

Tags: python-3.x

```
num=input(int("Enter thr number u want to print:"))
a=0
b=0
for i in range(1,num+1):
    if(i%2!=0):
     a=a+6
    else:
     b=b+7
     if (num % 2!=0):
      print("number is{}".format(a+6)

    else:
      print("number is{}".format(b+7)
```

The following error occurs during the execution of the code listing above:

> File "series", line 12
>       else:
>          ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Please help me understand what am I missing here.

Comment: Your indentation is off. You have `if-else-else`.

Answer (score 1):

The `else` on line 12 needs to be indented to the same level as it's corresponding `if` statement.

Python is picky about white-space and indentation.